# Android right to left language support

Tags: android

I'm developing an application, and don't want to support RTL . Here is my question: how to make my preference screen support RTL without making the whole application support RTL?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your minSdkVersion is Android 4.2 (API level 17), you can use:
`

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LayoutDirection

Otherwise:

```
ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(findViewById(R.id.view), ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```